# Expressão regular para validar um campo

Tags: jquery, html5, regex

Tenho um input no formulário que deve aceitar somente os seguintes formatos:

Exemplos

- 1AB
- 1AB2CD
- 1AB2CD3EF

O tamanho mínimo tem que ser 3 e o máximo 9, e precisa seguir sempre o padrão 1 dígito e 2 letras. Não deve ser aceito por exemplo 1AB2 ou 1AB2C.

Fiz assim:

```
[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

Mas nesse caso somente funciona para o primeiro exemplo que coloquei, não sei como fazer repetir o padrão.

Comment: Você algum código que já começou a escrever pra tentar resolver o seu problema? Mostre para nós.

Comment: Fiz assim: [0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2} 
Mas nesse caso somente funciona para o primeiro exemplo que coloquei, não sei como fazer repetir o padrão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer que o padrão "1 dígito, 2 letras" se repita no máximo 3 vezes, você pode usar o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{}`, indicando a quantidade mínima e máxima de vezes. No caso, o mínimo é 1, e o máximo é 3, então ficaria:

```
(\d[a-zA-Z]{2}){1,3}
```

Repare que troquei `[0-9]` por `\d`, pois [são equivalentes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)***** (ambos servem para dígitos). E removi o `{1}` porque é redundante, já que "1 repetição" é o padrão (`[0-9]{1}` é o mesmo que `[0-9]`).

E os parênteses são necessários, já que todo o conjunto "1 dígito, 2 letras" deve se repetir de 1 a 3 vezes.

Você pode ver esta regex funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/TmXuAl/1).

---

***** **Geralmente** `[0-9]` e `\d` são equivalentes. O único detalhe é que dependendo da linguagem/engine/configuração, o `\d` também pode corresponder a [outros caracteres que representam dígitos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), como por exemplo os caracteres `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes).

Comment: Muito obrigado!